# Delphi Android Remote Push Notification not work if App closed

Tags: delphi, google-cloud-messaging

I followed the following guideline to setup the Remote Push Notification Message on my Android device but it DOES NOT WORK if the app closed.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Multi-Device_Application_to_Receive_Push_Notifications

Anyone can give me the solutions and hints.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Not very sure, but maybe you need a service